# Driving directions with traffic

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-maps

How do I receive driving time between two locations with traffic. This information is displayed on iPhone maps application, when 'Show Traffic' option is selected.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to buy in as a >>[Maps business customer](http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html) and set the *durationInTraffic* property of the >>[DirectionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests) object to true:

> `durationInTraffic` *(optional)* specifies whether the `DirectionsLeg`
>   result should include a duration that takes into account current
>   traffic conditions. This feature is only available for Maps for
>   Business customers. The time in current traffic will only be returned
>   if traffic information is available in the requested area.

Without being a business customer you will not be able to take the current traffic situation into account for your directions calculations, but you can still >>[activate the traffic layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TrafficLayer) in Maps to show the current traffic situation on your map.